# dates from the DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the query in Snowflake:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,start_date ,end_date) as days
       ,start_date
       ,end_date 
from table1
```

It gives me no. of days as:

| days | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 |
| 28 | 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 |

but I need to find the dates for the days instead of just the no. of days i.e I want to see those all 14 dates instead of just no. of days.

can anyone help.

Comment: What does "The date for the days" mean? What date would you want to see instead of the number `14`? I ask because when you subtract a date from another date, you get an interval, not another date; so the question is confusing.

Comment: I want to see those all 14 dates instead of just no. of days

Comment: The interval you are saying between the start and end date, I want dates for those

Comment: "All 14 dates". That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so we will create a table like your example data:

```
create table date_data(start_date date, end_date date) as
  select * from values
  ('2022-09-03'::date, '2022-09-17'::date),
  ('2022-08-19'::date, '2022-09-16'::date);
```

and use your example SQL:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,start_date ,end_date) as days
       ,start_date
       ,end_date 
from date_data;
```

we get:

| DAYS | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 |
| 28 | 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 |

but "we want all the dates between these"

so lets use a table generator to make some rows ([GENERATOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html)), and for each row we will allocate a incrementing number with no gaps ([ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)), and then add those numbers so a known date to build a range of dates ([DATE_FROM_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html), [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html)):

```
select dateadd('day', row_number() over (order by null)-1, date_from_parts(1900,1, 1)) as date
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 10));
```

| DATE |
| --- |
| 1900-01-01 |
| 1900-01-02 |
| 1900-01-03 |
| 1900-01-04 |
| 1900-01-05 |
| 1900-01-06 |
| 1900-01-07 |
| 1900-01-08 |
| 1900-01-09 |
| 1900-01-10 |

Now 10 is not enouth, and 1900 is too early, so we can change those value.

Now we can build a date table, which is a wise thing to do, if you are going to work with date ranges a lot:

```
create table big_table_of_date as
select dateadd('day', row_number() over (order by null)-1, date_from_parts(1900,1, 1)) as date
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000));
```

or if you are doing a one off calculation you can use a CTE to hold those values, but this will be generated every time this SQL is run, so might be "costly" if run over large ranges millions of times...

```
with cte_big_table_of_date as (
    select dateadd('day', row_number() over (order by null)-1, date_from_parts(2022,1, 1)) as date
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
)  
select        
    d.start_date
   ,d.end_date 
   ,r.date
from date_data as d
join cte_big_table_of_date as r
    on r.date between d.start_date and d.end_date
order by 1,2,3;
```

| START_DATE | END_DATE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-19 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-20 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-21 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-22 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-23 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-24 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-25 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-26 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-27 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-28 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-29 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-30 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-08-31 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-01 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-02 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-03 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-04 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-06 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-07 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-08 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-09 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-10 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-11 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-12 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-13 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-14 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-15 |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-16 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-03 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-04 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-06 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-07 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-08 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-09 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-10 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-11 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-12 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-13 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-14 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-15 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-16 |
| 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-09-17 |

Comment: Thank you so much @SimeonPilgrim this worked perfectlly, all we have to want is to not include the last date, i.e end date ex. 2022-09-16, how can we do this

Comment: we also have dates for 2023 in that how should we use this as, its only applying for 2022

Comment: if you want the end date to not be in the results add to the join clause `on r.date between d.start_date and d.end_date and r.date < d.end_date` and if have a large date range, put a larger number in the generator.

Answer (score 2):

The dates could be generated by multiplying rows per difference of days:

```
SELECT table1.start_date
      ,table1.end_date
      ,table1.start_date + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY table1.start_date,
                                                          table1.end_date 
                                             ORDER BY NULL)-1 AS generated_date
FROM table1
, TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(SPACE(DATEDIFF('day', table1.start_date, table1.end_date))
        , ' ')) AS r;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1
AS
SELECT '2022-09-03'::DATE AS start_date, '2022-09-17'::DATE AS end_date UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-08-19'::DATE, '2022-09-16'::DATE;
```

Output (part):

[image]

Comment: I tried using this but it gives me some different output

Comment: Hello, when I tried this way dates getting generated which are not meant to like 2050, 2109 etc

Comment: @swarajnavthare The code is working for provided example. Most likely you have duplicates of dates(the same range for many rows in original table). You should PARTITION BY unique columns set which were not provided in the original question

Comment: could you please share how can I do that, I tried multiple ways but dose not seem to work, it give for example startdate : 2022-05-14 and end date : 2022-06-04 generated date upto :2024 or more

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a derived table that holds all dates in the overall date range needed for this table and then use that to your join your table back in:

```
WITH CTE_MY_DATE AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), '2000-01-01') AS MY_DATE
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10000))  
    WHERE MY_DATE BETWEEN 
        (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM table1)
        AND 
        (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM table1)
)
SELECT nct.calendar_date_column
   start_date, end_date
FROM new_calendar_table nct
   INNER JOIN table1 
      ON nct.calendar_date_column BETWEEN table1.start_date and table1.end_date
```

Comment: do I need to create a new table new_calendar_table for this

Comment: never use `SEQx()` for the numbers as they can have gaps (as per the doc's) only use `ROW_NUMBER()...`